# ~ does not resolve to Request.ApplicationPath when website is hosted inside a sub directory

Tags: asp.net

I have an asp.net website which is inside a sub directory from root.

example : `http:localhost:6464/MyWebsite`  OR `http://www.myDomain.com/MySite`

When i use a ASP.Net Image button and set its ImageUrl property as `"~/images/myimage.png"`, it does not resolve to `http:localhost:6464/MyWebsite/images/myimage.png` instead it resolves to  `http:localhost:6464/images/myimage.png` , and i get a error 200 (resource not found).

I read somewhere that for server controls i must use "~".

One solution i am currently using is , in webconfig i make an entry for BaseURL and set it as

```
http:localhost:6464/MyWebsite/
```

and then use it as `<asp:ImageButton ID="imgButton2" ImageURL="<%=Context.Items["baseURL"]%>images/myimage.png" runat="server"/>`.

This works but i am checking if there is a more elegant way.

**UPDATED:**

So,  **How to resolve to root of the application/virtual directory**
Thanks.

Comment: Also tried setting base tag as : 
`<base href="<%= Context.Items["baseURL"] %>" />` , but it works only with html elements and does not work with server control , ImageButton in my case.

Comment: `~` always resolves to the site root, not the root of the application/virtual directory.

Comment: @BrianDriscoll then what is the best solution you would advise.

Comment: Honestly the solution you've come up with is probably the way to go; I can't think of a better "shortcut."

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue solved in this way:

in the code behind page of the site.master I added:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    this.Page.DataBind();
    ...
}
```

All server side controls has the "~/" as it should be. E.g.:

```
<asp:Image ID="ImageSpace" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/spacer.gif" />
<asp:HyperLink ID="LinkMenuXXX" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/xxx.aspx"/>
```

Required client side controls has the following model (e.g.):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='<%# ResolveUrl("~/")%>js/cookie/jquery.cookie.js'></script>
```

I hope it helps

Comment: it doesnt help. "~" refers still refers to website root. I want to resolve to root of the application/virtual directory.